# How to have an Azure test and production website

Tags: testing, azure

I'm in the process of switching to Azure and had a question about my setup. I'm running 2 Azure websites....1 for test and 1 for production. I've linked my team foundation service account to my test website, which works great for continuous integration. When I'm happy with the build on the test site, I want to push it to the production website. The only way I can see how this can be done is to just manually deploy from my local machine straight to the production website, which I don't want to do. Is there any other way this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that I see is to link your TFS service to the production WebSite also. Then edit the build definition which was auto created during the linking, and make it not CI build (executed upon every check-in) but rather be a "Manual trigger". Then, when you want to push to production, trigger that build.

**Update**

Somehow I knew there will be question on editing the build definition. Just open the "Team Explorer", Navigate to "Builds", right click on your Build definition and click "Edit" on the context menu:

[image: Tfs Edit Build Definition]

**UPDATE 2**

Despite the fact that this changes to pure TFS/Build definition question, I will just add - note that when you first linked your dev/test site, it created one build definition targeting that site. When you link the production website, to ***the same solution in your TFS***, it will create another build definition targeting that production website. Now you will have two build definitions for the same ***Team Project***. You, in fact can have as many build definitions as you like (you can even manually create ones). Rest is build configuration editing, deserving another question, most probably on ServerFault.

Comment: That sounds great. How do you edit the build definition that was created during the linking?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I'm still not sure though how you target a website on Azure from a build definition. If you can't do that, it doesn't matter if your build in continuous or manual; you'll still deploy the code to both the test and production websites when the build is kicked off.